# Define default cache drake in global environment

Tags: r, drake-r-package

i have a drake plan and intend to switch the cache directory based on the input data (i.e. input-dir1 -> results-dir1). This has the advantage, that I don't need to rerun the full pipeline, if the data source switches.

Functions like `make` or `loadd` seem to always use `find_cache`, which defaults to the `.drake` dir in the current R workspace.

Is there a way to define an default cache in the current global environment that is not in the .drake dir? I would like avoid to define the cache manually in every call to `make`, `clean`, or `loadd` via the parameter `cache`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cache switching is uncommon, and it usually increases brittleness and decreases reproducibility. So I usually discourage it and have no plans to implement a global setting to set the cache. In your case, you can set your own global option or environment variable and supply it to the `cache` argument. There are [ways to change the default value of `cache`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=default), but please be careful.

Comment: I guess not the answer i was looking for, but reasonable. thx.